# Can I update variable products in Woocommerce using the import feature?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, export, updates

I'm trying to update many products at once in my Woocommerce. I thought that exporting everything, changing prices in Excel and importing back in with the update option checked would work.

It does... but only for simple products, variable products aren't updated and their stock and price stay the same.

I can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong or not or if this is not supported (although this seems like such a basic feature).

Comment: Did you tried to delete product transients in WooCommerce settings > Status > tools.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec no, but I didn't see any changes in the admin. I'll try, but I'm assuming transients are relevant only for the front end in this case.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec clearing the transients have no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Yes you are right! … Variable products and product variations are a real complication…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some fiddling, I've figured it out.

For some reason, if Simple and Variable products are exported and imported in the same file, variations don't update.

So, to successfully update variable products and their variations we have to export Simple and Variable products separately.